# There are still some patches that turtle can move on to but ERROR

Tags: netlogo

I ask a turtle A to move to patch that has a neighbor that has the same type of turtle with the turtle A. It is working well until the ERROR (MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead) comes out. Visually there are still some available patches. How to code so that all available patches are occupied and report or stop the program when there is no more patch to occupy? Any comments will be really helpful. I did the following:

```
to set-move
 ask migrants
  [let pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
   let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] = 1]
    ifelse target != 0 and (status != "resident") [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                              set status "resident"
                                              set color blue]
                                              []   
  ] 

end
```

This is the full code

```
breed [migrants migrant]
breed [residents resident]

patches-own [value]
turtles-own [income
status]

to setup
  ca
  let total problo + probmid + probhi
  if (total != 100) 
     [print (word "prob is more than 100")]
  ask patches [set value random-normal 10 3
  let patch-value value
    set pcolor scale-color (gray - 5) patch-value 10 3]
  ask patches
  [if random 100 < 3
    [sprout-residents 1
      [set color red
       set shape "default"
       set size 1
       set status "resident"   
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to go

  ask patches 
  [if random 100 < 1 
    [sprout-migrants 1
      [set color green
       set shape "default"
       set size 1 
        set status "migrant"
       set-move 
  ]]]

end

to set-move
 ask migrants
  [let pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
   let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] = 1]
    ifelse target != 0 and (status != "resident") [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                              set status "resident"
                                              set color blue]
                                              []   
  ] 

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line: `let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] = 1]` identifies the patches where there is exactly 1 neighbour meeting those conditions. So a patch with 2 such neighbours is would not be available. From your description I think you really want >= instead of =:

`let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]`

Comment: Thanks JenB. I consider several number of neighbors, that is really helpful.

However, as you can see, the added figure is the last condition of the simulation before the error. There should be some patches (yellow circle: patch with neighbour with the same type of turtle) that turtles can occupy. Why are those "neglected"? Which part is incorrect?

Comment: Look at your top yellow middle circle. If I understand correctly what you are doing, then it has 2 neighbours with a blue turtle. So `[count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]]` will return the value 2. Open an inspect window at that patch and type `count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]`. What number do you get?

Comment: Thanks JenB. I got it now. It is 2, that is why it is blank. The last one, as you see here 
` ifelse target != 0 and (status != "resident") [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                              set status "resident"
                                              set color blue]
                                              [] `
What should I write here
`
                                            []
`
to end the process when there is no more available patches? I used stop and die but both did not work.

Comment: Just use `if` instead of `ifelse` and nothing will happen for those where there is no available patch. I can't see any time progression in your model, so I don't know what you mean by stopping a process,. This should only happen once each time you run the go procedure. If you want to ask about something else, ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.